# Let users assign particular roles to other users

Tags: 7, users

How can I let a "subadmin" to **assign only particular roles to other users**?

Just an example: my users can only use the forum if they have the "*forum user*" role. I would like to delegate the right to a "subadmin" to assign the "*forum user*" role to particular users, without letting this subadmin to be able to assign any other roles. Or I also want to let this subadmin assign the "*article creator*" role to others, etc.

Is there a module for that? Or do I have to create my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope [Role Delegation](http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module solves your problem !

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role

Comment: Wow, thank you! I just tried it, and this is simply perfect for the task! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag)  and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules.

1. Make a flag for each role.
2. Give the subadmin permissions to flag/unflag.
3. For each flag, add a rule that adds the relevant role on flagging and another rule that removes the relevant role upon unflagging.

Comment: +1, thank you for the idea! Finally I chose the Role Delegation module, which is a lightweight and really simple to use module, which is just enough. :)